# (R) Markdown: how to define a new paragraph without inserting an empty line?

Tags: r, vim, r-markdown, markdown, rstudio

I am using R Markdown in RStudio to write a presentation, together with the VIM key bindings.

In VIM, I can type `{` to move up a code block, and `}` to move down a code block.

It is my understanding that code blocks in this setting are separated by newlines.

I want to use this keybinding to move up and down different slides of my presentation.

But I also want to put more than one paragraph in a single slide. Is there an alternative in Markdown to write a new paragraph without inserting a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I can just "simulate" a new paragraph like that

```
Line line line\
\
New paragraph
```

It will display "like" a new paragraph but doesn't require a blank line, allowing me to use the `{` keybinding to switch between slides